# How to programmatically invoke Ctrl+Alt+Del window in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, windows-7, credential-providers

I am developing custom credential provider dll for Windows 7.
This has a condition check; if it fails I want to show <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> window.

Which function can I call to invoke the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>(SAS) window?

Comment: This may interest you: http://support.citrixonline.com/en_us/gotomypc/all_files/gtc140010. It seems, that under some circumstances user may prevent you from sending the SAS.

Comment: @CodeRider Wha-? `int main() { /* insert code here */ }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending the message Ctrl+Alt+Del from my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597959/sending-the-message-ctrlaltdel-from-my-application)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is No such APIs exists.If you are so particular, try sending the key press sequence of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> combination using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in your code. This will surely invoke SAS window.

Actually we cannot hook <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination. In Windows XP it was possible by customizing GINA.dll. In between the window you are talking about is called the Winlogon desktop. It is also called secure desktop.

It wiil be invoked internally by windows only on certain situations like on start up, when the system is locked etc.

If you are trying to run customized application on winlogon desktop it is possible by using your customized credential provider. The credential provider dll can invoke any applications during start up of windows. It cannot entirely replace the default winlogon desktop.

It is meant for adding customized log in mechanisms in Windows 7. Have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

Comment: Thanks CodeRIder.i already read that link.But i just want to know,there is any windows function for invoke Ctrl+alt+del(SAS) like sendSAS.

Comment: There were APIs for interaction with Winlogon in earlier versions of Windows like WlxSASNotify, WlxLoggedONSas etc. as given in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376105(v=vs.85).aspx) . But these APIs are not supported in Windows 7

Comment: i can show message box after i enter the submit button in log on time.but,after that message box shown i want to stop that process and show the switch user tiles or ctrl+alt+del or current user tile.

Comment: In the submit button you may also call PostQuitMessage(). By default after your dialog closes, you can view the SAS window i guess.

Comment: No,its not working.it destroy or hide the previous message box only.

Comment: Try using exit() or ExitProcess() instead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30824/discussion-between-coderider-and-sanju-monu)