# How TeamViewer simulates Ctrl-Alt-Del on Windows programmatically?

Tags: c++, security, winapi, teamviewer

How TeamViewer and other remote control software simulate the Alt-Ctr-Del keypress, also known as the Windows Secure Attention Sequence (SAS)?

1. Many forums state that this is not possible, but the facts are against them. :)
2. [SendSAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sas/nf-sas-sendsas) function looks the most obvious answer, but that requires Group Policy changes, [UIPI bypass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation), etc. so it's definitely not what that the run-only TeamViewer does.
3. Another common suggestion is using the proprietary SasLibEx library, but that is discontinued and [works only up to Windows Vista](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2008/12/23/locking-a-workstation-part-2/).
4. [An old Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047344/net-simulate-ctrlaltdel-sendkeys) has a near miss, but it does not work with newer Windows
5. `SendInput` does not work for Alt-Ctrl-Del, neither if it is sent to `winsta0\winlogon` desktop
6. `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_HOTKEY, 0, MAKELONG( MOD_CONTROL | MOD_ALT, VK_DELETE));` - nope
7. [WmsgSendMessage](http://www.atelierweb.com/ctrlaltdel/) was tried on the next man's suggestion, it proved no better or different than SendSAS.
8. [Keyboard filter drivers](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/input/kbfiltr) could be a solution, but they need code signing and special privileges to install, and implementing them is neither for the faint hearted. I also verified with `driverquery` that the run-only Team Viewer does not install drivers.

**So, any idea how others do it?**

The [Internals of SAS implementation](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2228450&seqNum=8) gives a good overview of what it is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: SendInput() function?

Comment: No, not SendInput

Comment: @lorand there is open source remote sotware, what does it do?

Comment: In my own app which uses [Sharing Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/rdpencomapi/nn-rdpencomapi-irdpsrapisharingsession)  there is a send keystroke API.

Comment: @michael It is well known that the SAS can't be generated by faking input

Comment: @David Heffernan - more precisely?

Comment: @Lorlin Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597959/sending-the-message-ctrlaltdel-from-my-application). It seems using an API of SASLib that is not public.

Comment: I just tested with **UiAutomation**.. It works (at least on my OS ( _Windows 10 - 1803, 17134.829_ )), but it is not the best method...

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that there is an undocumented *Secure Desktop LRPC Interface* aka. *Winlogon RPC Interface* used by the Windows components themselves and some third party libraries as well. Here is everything I got about it:

- [Internals of SAS implementation](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2228450&seqNum=8) from Mark E. Russinovich book gives a very good overview what is happening behind the scenes
- Two obscure sites give some details about the interface itself, but for me this is too little to use them. ([Link 1](http://redplait.blogspot.com/2010/11/winlogonexe-rpc-interfaces.html), [Link 2](https://gist.github.com/masthoon/510dd757b21f04da47431e9d4e0a3f6e))

Comment: Did you figure out a way to simulate CAD?

Comment: Nope. Submit an answer to the post if you did.